# VimDiff as Git MergeTool : How To resolve all merge conflicts with changes from LOCAL,BASE or REMOTE with one command?

Tags: git, merge, conflict, vimdiff

I want to know :
How To resolve all merge conflicts  with changes from LOCAL,BASE or REMOTE with one command ?
This must be possible right ? I am struggling with this for 2 hours now....

Or is there even a possibility without vimdiff ?

thank you

Comment: If my answer helped solve your problem, please consider accepting it.

Answer (score 1):

When you launch `git mergetool`, 4 filse are created for vimdiff to view:

- `filename_BASE_suffix`
- `filename_LOCAL_suffix`
- `filename_REMOTE_suffix`
- `filename_BACKUP_suffix`

With vimdiff still running, if one of these files is the one you want to keep, you can go to your shell and do, say, `cp filename_LOCAL_suffix filename`, and then go back to vimdiff where you can reload the file (if prompted) or just exit without saving anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this on the vimdiff prompt
`g/<<< HEAD/diffg LO`
Theoretically like this you always grab the LOCAL changes wherever there is a merge conflict.
Don't know if it always works, but it'll get you a long way.